# DataTable columns are set as ReadOnly when using a union

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, union

I'm trying to get a `DataTable` and update it later in my program, however I'm receiving a `System.Exception` when trying to modify one of my columns (IsUsed).The error reads 'Column IsUsed is read only'. Which is true, the column in the `DataTable` has the `ReadOnly` property set as true.

Here's my C# code which generates my SQL:

```
public IgnoredPositionSet GetAllForReconciliation(int aReconciliationId)
{   
      SqlGenerator internalIgnoredPositionSqlGenerator = base.GetCoreSqlGenerator()
        .Select.Add(@"
          IP.SecurityId,
          IP.SecurityName,
          IP.Quantity,
          NULL AS AccountTypeName")
        .Join.Add($@"
          LEFT JOIN 
            (
              SELECT
                ReconciliationId,
                MatchId,
                SecurityId,
                SecurityName,
                SUM(QuantityTradeDate) AS Quantity
              FROM [PositionReconciliation.InternalPosition]
              GROUP BY
                ReconciliationId,
                MatchId,
                SecurityId,
                SecurityName
            ) IP
          ON IP.ReconciliationId = {ServiceTableAlias}.ReconciliationId
          AND IP.MatchId         = {ServiceTableAlias}.MatchId")
        .Where.Add("IsInternalPosition = 1");

      SqlGenerator externalIgnoredPositionSqlGenerator = GetCoreSqlGenerator()
        .Select.Add(@"
          NULL AS SecurityId,
          EP.SecurityName,
          EP.Quantity,
          AccountTypeName")
        .Join.Add($@"
          LEFT JOIN 
            (
              SELECT
                ReconciliationId,
                MatchId,
                SecurityName,
                SUM(QuantityTradeDate) AS Quantity
              FROM [PositionReconciliation.ExternalPosition]
              GROUP BY
                ReconciliationId,
                MatchId,
                SecurityName
            ) EP
          ON EP.ReconciliationId = {ServiceTableAlias}.ReconciliationId
          AND EP.MatchId         = {ServiceTableAlias}.MatchId")
        .Join.Add($@"
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                EP.ReconciliationId,
                EP.MatchId,
                A.AccountTypeId,
                AT.Name AS AccountTypeName
              FROM [PositionReconciliation.ExternalPosition] EP
              LEFT JOIN [Core.CustodianFund.AccountMap]      A  ON A.Id  = EP.CustodianAccountId
              LEFT JOIN [Reconciliation.Cash.AccountType]    AT ON AT.Id = A.AccountTypeId
              GROUP BY ReconciliationId, MatchId, AccountTypeId, AT.Name
            ) EPAT
          ON  EPAT.ReconciliationId = {ServiceTableAlias}.ReconciliationId
          AND EPAT.MatchId          = {ServiceTableAlias}.MatchId")
        .Where.Add("IsInternalPosition = 0");

      var internalPositions = GetEntitySet(internalIgnoredPositionSqlGenerator); //ReadOnly props are false
      var externalPositions = GetEntitySet(externalIgnoredPositionSqlGenerator); //ReadOnly props are false

      return GetEntitySet($"SELECT * FROM ({internalIgnoredPositionSqlGenerator} UNION ALL {externalIgnoredPositionSqlGenerator}) {ServiceTableAlias} WHERE {nameof(IgnoredPosition.ReconciliationId)} = {aReconciliationId}");
```

The resulting SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
  SERVICE_TABLE.*,
  IP.SecurityId,
  IP.SecurityName,
  IP.Quantity,
  NULL AS AccountTypeName
FROM [PositionReconciliation.IgnoredPosition] SERVICE_TABLE
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
ReconciliationId,
MatchId,
SecurityId,
SecurityName,
SUM(QuantityTradeDate) AS Quantity
FROM [PositionReconciliation.InternalPosition]
GROUP BY
ReconciliationId,
MatchId,
SecurityId,
SecurityName
) IP
ON IP.ReconciliationId = SERVICE_TABLE.ReconciliationId
AND IP.MatchId         = SERVICE_TABLE.MatchId
WHERE
(IsInternalPosition = 1)
 UNION ALL
  SELECT
  SERVICE_TABLE.*,
  NULL AS SecurityId,
  EP.SecurityName,
  EP.Quantity,
  AccountTypeName
FROM [PositionReconciliation.IgnoredPosition] SERVICE_TABLE
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
ReconciliationId,
MatchId,
SecurityName,
SUM(QuantityTradeDate) AS Quantity
FROM [PositionReconciliation.ExternalPosition]
GROUP BY
ReconciliationId,
MatchId,
SecurityName
) EP
ON EP.ReconciliationId = SERVICE_TABLE.ReconciliationId
AND EP.MatchId         = SERVICE_TABLE.MatchId
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
EP.ReconciliationId,
EP.MatchId,
A.AccountTypeId,
AT.Name AS AccountTypeName
FROM [PositionReconciliation.ExternalPosition] EP
LEFT JOIN [Core.CustodianFund.AccountMap]      A  ON A.Id  = EP.CustodianAccountId
LEFT JOIN [Reconciliation.Cash.AccountType]    AT ON AT.Id = A.AccountTypeId
GROUP BY ReconciliationId, MatchId, AccountTypeId, AT.Name
) EPAT
ON  EPAT.ReconciliationId = SERVICE_TABLE.ReconciliationId
AND EPAT.MatchId          = SERVICE_TABLE.MatchId
WHERE
(IsInternalPosition = 0)
```

Here is the code which creates the `DataSet`:

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string                       aCommandText,
                          IEnumerable<DbDataParameter> aParameters            = null,
                          int?                         aCommandTimeoutSeconds = null,
                          bool                         aIsUpdateable          = true)
{
  var da

taSet = new DataSet
      {
        Locale             = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        EnforceConstraints = false
      };

      return PerformDbOperation(new DbOperationInfo(aCommandText, aCommandTimeoutSeconds, aParameters),
                                aDbOperationInfo => 
                                {
                                  DataAdapter.SelectCommand       = aDbOperationInfo.Command;
                                  DataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = aIsUpdateable ? MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey : MissingSchemaAction.Add;
                                  DataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

                                  if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
                                    aDbOperationInfo.AffectedRowCount = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

                                  return dataSet;
                                });
    }
```

I've been playing around with this and I've discovered that without the `union` the `DataTable` fills fine and sets the `ReadOnly` property on the columns as false. So I know it has something to do with the union but I'm not sure why.

I know this question has been asked in a similar way before but I don't want to loop around the `DataTable` columns and manually set the `ReadOnly` property to true, I'd like to fix the issue at the source.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I believe it's because the columns are being classed as 'computed' columns which the C# code will default readonly to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote it the wrong way round? The ReadOnly flag is true and you are hoping to avoid looping and set it as false.

Were you to provide a simple select, the query builder would be able to create matching update and delete queries, map columns to parameters and a writable dataset would be generated. It can't do that for complexities inherent in a union query because it would take some serious amount of coding logic to work out whether the columns are updatable, which table they're from, whether the same columns are presented in the same way etc.. it's not designed to be that sophisticated web mostlynits for consuming simple select queries

Just set the columns to be writable and provide an update query manually to the builder/adapter - trying to fudge things so that the process that creates the data table from the data can guess not to make these columns read only is going to be a considerable waste of time and probably quite fragile..

The other option you have is to not do your union, do two fills on two different queries from the adapter instead, it will have a better chance of generating an updatable dataset and command collection if the queries are free of joins, union, groups etc

Or use the dataset designer and create a new dataset that is designed and strongly typed to represent what you need

Of all the options, I'd pick the last you're trying to do this "properly" - data containers/classes should be designed and strongly typed; using a generic dataset isn't much "better" than storing everything in an object[][][]